# vmware_vm_facts vCenter password validation failing

Tags: module, automation, ansible, vmware, devops

I am using Ansible and vCenter to provision a VM. When I run my playbook, I get an authentication error:

`Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password.`

However, using the same credentials, I am able to log into vCenter manually.

Here is my simplified playbook:

```
---
- name: create a new VM on an ESX server
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:

    - name: include vars
      include_vars:
        dir: 'group_vars/prod'
        files_matching: 'secret-esx.yml'

    - name: gather facts from target host
      local_action:
        module: vmware_vm_facts
        hostname: vi-devops-esx9.lab.vi.local
        username: "{{ esx_username }}"
        password: "{{ esx_password }}"
        validate_certs: no
      register: qe_facts
```

Why can I access vCenter, but vmware_vm_facts cannot with the same credentials?

Answer (score 0):

My hostname was incorrect. Fixing my hostname fixed the authentication error.